# More efficient way to retrieve data from JSON

Tags: performance, c, parsing, json

I am using the [jsmn JSON parser](http://zserge.bitbucket.org/jsmn.html) ([source code](https://raw.github.com/noct/jsmn/master/jsmn.c)) to get extract data from a JSON string.  jsmn stores the data in tokens that just point to the token boundaries in the JSON string instead of copying the data. For example, jsmn will create tokens like:

- `Object [0..31]`
- `String [3..7], String [12..16], String [20..23]`
- `Number [27..29]`

This method is used to retrieve the actual characters between those values (for String objects):

```
char* getTextFromJSON(const char *json)
{
    json_parser p;
    jsontok_t tokens[15];
    jsontok_t key;

    if (!json) return NULL;

    initJsonParser(&p);
    parseJson(&p, json, tokens, sizeof(tokens) / sizeof(tokens[0]));
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(tokens) / sizeof(tokens[0]); ++i)
    {
        key = tokens[i];
        unsigned int length = key.end - key.start;
        char keyString[length + 1];
        memcpy(keyString, &json[key.start], length);
        keyString[length] = '\0';
        if(!strcmp(keyString, "utterance"))
        {
            key = tokens[i + 1];
            length = key.end - key.start;
            char* keyString = (char*) malloc(length + 1);
            memcpy(keyString, &json[key.start], length);
            keyString[length] = '\0';
            return keyString;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Here are some JSON examples that would be thrown into the parser:

```
{"status":0,"id":"432eac38858968c108899cc6c3a4bade-1","hypotheses" [{"utterance":"test","confidence":0.84134156}]}
```

```
{"status":5,"id":"695118aaa3d01dc2ac4aa8054d1e5bb0-1","hypotheses":[]}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few issues with `getTextFromJSON` involving use of pointers, code
duplication and use of an inappropriate function.

Pointers first.  In this code:

```
jsontok_t tokens[15];
jsontok_t key;
...
key = tokens[i];
```

you are copying the token when you could be using a pointer:

```
jsontok_t *key = &tokens[i];
```

Copying is obviously more costly than pointing.  Also note that it is often
best to define the variable at its first point of use.

---

There are two points of duplication, one determining the size of the token
array and one concerned with copying the string.  Instead of this:

```
jsontok_t tokens[15];
...
parseJson(&p, json, tokens, sizeof(tokens) / sizeof(tokens[0]));
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(tokens) / sizeof(tokens[0]); ++i)
```

I would do either:

```
#define N_TOKENS 15
jsontok_t tokens[N_TOKENS];
...
parseJson(&p, json, tokens, N_TOKENS);
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < N_TOKENS; ++i)
```

or

```
jsontok_t tokens[15];
#define N_TOKENS (sizeof tokens / sizeof tokens[0])  // or const int N_TOKENS inseatd of #define 
...etc
```

The string copying code-duplication is actually unnecessary if you use a
better standard library function...

---

Instead of using `strcmp` to compare the string (which involves constructing
the string because it lacks a \0):

```
    if(!strcmp(keyString, "utterance"))
```

use `memcmp`.  And you can use `strndup` to create a copy of the key.  If you
don't have `strndup` which is non-standard, you can easily write it (in a
separate function).

These changes wont speed it up much, but are certainly cleaner:

```
char* getTextFromJSON(const char *json)
{
    if (!json) return NULL;

    json_parser p;
    #define N_TOKENS 15  // this normally would be at the start of the file
    jsontok_t tokens[N_TOKENS];

    initJsonParser(&p);
    int n = parseJson(&p, json, tokens, N_TOKENS);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        jsontok_t *key = &tokens[i];
        if (!memcmp("utterance", &json[key->start], (size_t) (key->end - key->start))) {
            ++key;
            return strndup(&json[key->start], (size_t)(key->end - key->start));
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: +1 for all the great suggestions, but the empty JSON gives a "Segmentation fault" because no utterance exists in the JSON.  How would I go about fixing that?  Once it is fixed I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: So if the utterance is not found the function returns NULL to the caller (eg in `main`).  You need to test for that in `main`, so something like `if ((text = getTextFromJSON(json)) != NULL) { /* do something with text */ }`. Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Right now I'm doing it with a ternary operator: `printf("Text: %s", text ? text : "No text recognized.")`, but it still segfaults.

Comment: Upon changing the last `return NULL` to `return "No text recognized"`, it still segfaults, odd.

Comment: Do you know exactly where it segfaults - have you run it in a debugger?

Comment: On the 8th execution of the `for` loop, it fails on the conditional `memcmp()` test.

Comment: Your problem is most likely that you are looping through tokens that don't exist.  You should use the number of tokens found, presumably returned by `parseJson`, as the loop limit.  I have updated the code above to illustrate.

Comment: No, it returns `JSON_SUCCESS` which is a `jsonerr_t`.

Comment: When I try to print the value of every token in the loop to see what is going on it segfaults.  I'm using `printf("Token[%d]: %s", i, strndup(&json[key->start], (size_t)(key->end - key->start)))` right after assigning `key` a value.

Comment: There must be a way of finding out how many of your `tokens[]` array contain valid data after the call to `jsonParse`. As you say, it is not the return value, so it must either be in the `json_parser p` parser or in the tokens themselves (initialised to a defined value for example).

Comment: It turns out that it was a missed corner case of not checking for an empty token.  I've put that and a bit more into my answer, but I'll keep this one as accepted since you got me very close to the final method I have now.

Answer (score 6):

### Improvements

Check if `parseJson()` returns an error code.

```
int err = parseJson(&p, json, tokens, TOKEN_NUMBER);
if (err)
{
       fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing JSON: %d\n", err);
       return NULL;
}
```

---

The code initializes all of the structures, but `->start` and `->end` will equal -1, which is why `memcmp()` will fail sometimes.

```
for (i = parser->toknext; i < num_tokens; i++) {
    jsmn_fill_token(&tokens[i], JSMN_PRIMITIVE, -1, -1);
}
```

Checking for a -1 value in `->start` or `->end` should be sufficient.

```
if ((key->end - key->start) < 0) return NULL;
```

---

The `tokens[]` array is uninitialized before it is passed to `parseJson()`, so once you iterate beyond the last token, the code is trying to run `memcmp()` on uninitialized nonsense address values. Initialize `tokens[]` to something and then check for that initialization value in the start/end fields during in the `for()` loop.

```
memset(&tokens, 0, sizeof(tokens));
```

---

During each iteration of the loop check for length zero to see if the token is actually valid before passing it to `memcmp()`. Bail out of the loop if the token has length zero.

```
if (!memcmp("", &json[key->start], (size_t) (key->end - key->start))) return NULL;
```

---

Add a test case for a blank token.

```
if (!memcmp("", &json[key->start], (size_t) (key->end - key->start))) return NULL;
```

---

### Final Code

```
#define TOKEN_NUMBER 15
char* getTextFromJSON(const char *json)
{
        if (!json) return NULL;

        json_parser p;
        jsontok_t tokens[TOKEN_NUMBER];
        memset(&tokens, 0, sizeof(tokens));
        initJsonParser(&p);
        int err = parseJson(&p, json, tokens, TOKEN_NUMBER);
        if (err)
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error parsing JSON: %d\n", err);
                return NULL;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < TOKEN_NUMBER; ++i)
        {
                jsontok_t *key = &tokens[i];
                if ((key->end - key->start) < 0) return NULL;
                if (!memcmp("", &json[key->start], (size_t) (key->end - key->start))) return NULL;
                if (!memcmp("utterance", &json[key->start], (size_t) (key->end - key->start)))
                {
                        ++key;
                        return strndup(&json[key->start], (size_t) (key->end - key->start));
                }
        }
        return NULL;
}
```